# Fundamental theorem of calculus for a bounded increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, bounded-variation, monotone-functions

Assume that $f$ is a bounded increasing function over an interval $I$ (possibly an unbounded interval)
Then we know that $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable. How would one prove that :

$$ \sup_I f - \inf_I f = \int_I f' $$

Comment: Of course in cases like this you would need to give some context. What do you know, what have you tried so far. Besides as pointed out what you want us to prove is actually false.

Comment: I was wrong, I missread the proof of a theorem. What is actually true is only one inequality :
$ \int_I f' \leq \sup_I f - \inf_I f$ It can be found in Giovani Leoni's book A first course on sobolev spaces page 44 corollary 1.37

Comment: Do you think this is still a valid question? I mean that you misread the statement and got something that's not true. I assume that Leoni's book does not include a proof for $\int f'\le \sup f-\inf f$, otherwise even the question for the actual statement would be questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't (i.e. this isn't true). Take for example the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) which has almost everywhere derivative $0$ but clearly changes so that the difference between the sup and inf is non-zero.

Comment: Do you really have to use such a patological counter example? Since continuity wasn't part of the requirement I'd think a simple step function would do...

Comment: @skyking Sometimes users think that they can get away with it if they change their hypotheses to be a bit stronger, eg. continuity. This is especially common in questions like this without context where it seems likely the op intuited it to be true and is seeking something more general to prove (not just necessarily the original problem statement). This anticipates and precludes that.